# Set JComboBox selected index inside JTable

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox renderer (and cell editor) inside of a JTable cell.

My JComboBox has two items ("a" and "b")

I would like to set the JComboBox selected index to 1 (corresponding to "b").

I've tried unsuccessfully to get the renderer component, and calling "setSelectedIndex(1")

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to set the JComboBox selected index to 1 (corresponding to "b").

You don't set the index.

The editor is shared by all rows in the table. The combo box item is selected when the cell starts editing. This is done automatically.

So all you need to do is add the proper data to the TableModel.

So in your case the value "b" needs to be added to the TableModel for the row when you create the TableModel.

Edit:

> my JComboBox is a renderer within a JTable.

The custom renderer would look something like:

```
class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer
{
    public ComboBoxRenderer()
    {
        setBorder(null);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        removeAllItems();
        addItem( value );

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I expressly desire to set the index.  For example, my available choices are "a" and "b".  When the user clicks (for example), some JButton, I want the visible selected option to be "b"

Comment: My two pieces of data ("a" and "b") are already in the data model.  By default, the first data string is displayed ("a").  I wish to display a different index (1, corresponding to "b").    I believe you are wrong, and that it can be done.  Perhaps you misunderstood my question.

Comment: To clarify, my data model already has BOTH "a" and "b" (as String []), with the JComboBox constructor using the String[].

Comment: @user6013878, no, the data model doesn't store the data as a String Array. It simply stores the data in the model as a String. Whenever you edit the cell the String is stored automatically in the model. You responded to may last comment in 2 minutes. That did not give you time to follow the link, download the code and test the code. I gave you link to a working example. Follow the link, download the code and test it!!! Also, see edit for a custom renderer..

Comment: While I appreciate your example, it is definitely NOT the same as my example.  You have an editor (stores string array) AND a data model.  Your data model REPEATS the same string that is stored in the editor.  So, of course, if the data model is set to the new string, it will appear in the table.       In my example, I have a single model ONLY, with a RENDERER (so that the cell appears like a combobox, unlike in your example, where the cell does not appear like a combobox until it is clicked).  My model DOES CONTAIN an array of strings.  I cannot remove items (nor do I want to) from the model.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with render, it can be right to work with JComboBox model:

```
String[] vls = new String[]{"a","b"};
JComboBox<String> comboBox1;
...


comboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(vls));
```

You can use, when you work with ComboBox model:

```
comboBox1.getModel().setSelectedItem("b");
```

or, when you work without ComboBox model:

```
comboBox1.setSelectedIndex(1);
```

Comment: The combo box is used by all the rows in the table. You can't just set a selected index The renderer or editor will simply display the value from the TableModel in the combo box.

Comment: Hi: Your answer is for a plain JComboBox (by itself).  However, my JComboBox is a renderer within a JTable.

Comment: Thank you, maybe, I was inattentive, I am sorry for that